# How to count all comments of a post of an user in laravel elloquent model?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My One to many relation declaration code in user model..

```
public function post()
{
   $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'userid','id');// id--from user
}
```

My One to many relation declaration code in Post model..

```
  public function comment()
{
   $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'postid','pid');// id--from post
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all comment of an user but how?

Answer (score 2):

Try in User Model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
               'App\Comment', 'App\Post', 
               'userid', 'postid', 'id'
    );
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

comments are not related to users there, what you can query is "all comments in posts of a user"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change your model methods and pluralize it:

User model:

```
public function posts()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'userid','id');// id--from user
}
```

Post model:

```
public function comments()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'postid','pid');// id--from post
}
```

after this you can do it in your controller to count user's comments:

```
$user->posts->comments->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if postModel has

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

$comments = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

it should show like this

```
 Collection {#268 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Post {#275 ▶}
  ]
}
```

it should work with an loop like this

```
foreach ($posts as $post) { echo $post->comments_count; }
```